# Resque Scheduler not updating model as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, resque, resque-scheduler

I'm using resque-scheduler to schedule posts to the Twitter API. In my database I have a `SocialMediaPost` model with a `post_tweet` method that queries the API and then updates the record with the id of the tweet. When I run this code outside of resque-scheduler, it works as expected. When I queue a post though, everything in my `if/else` block is seemingly being skipped over. If I go to my Twitter account, I can see that the post was successful, yet when I check the database entry, there is no `twitter_id`, `twitter_uid`, or `twitter_link` for the entry.

Here is my `SocialMediaPost` model:

```
class SocialMediaPost < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'postman'
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :employer
    belongs_to :identity
    validates :post, length: {in: 0..140}, if: Proc.new { |t| t.twitter }
    validates :post, length: {in: 0..256}, if: Proc.new { |t| t.linkedin }
    after_commit :enqueue

    def enqueue
        time = scheduled_time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
        options = {
            id: self.id,
            services: JSON.parse(self.services),
            posts: JSON.parse(self.posts),
            attachment_url: self.attachment_url,
            media_url: self.media_url,
            time: scheduled_time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
        }
        Resque.enqueue_at(time, Postman, options)
    end

    def post_tweet
        tweet = company.twitter_client.update(JSON.parse(posts)['twitter'])
        if tweet.created?
            uid = self.company.identities.find_by(provider: :twitter).uid
            self.update_columns(twitter_id: tweet.id, twitter_uid: uid, twitter_link: "https://twitter.com/#{uid}/status/#{self.twitter_id}")
        end
        tweet.created?
    end
end
```

Here is my resque worker `Postman`:

```
class Postman
    @queue = :social_media_posts

    def self.perform(options)
        post = SocialMediaPost.find(options['id'])
        post.post_tweet if options['services']['twitter'] && options['attachment_url'].blank?
        post.post_tweet_with_media if options['services']['twitter'] && options['attachment_url'].present?
        post.post_linkedin_status if options['services']['linkedin']
    end
end
```

I've tried inserting a `binding.pry` in several spots, but resque skips over the bindings. Note that I'm using the `update_columns` method as a way of circumventing [this bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14493) that creates an infinite loop.

Comment: do you see the job in redis in the `delayed` queue?

Comment: Yes. I also checked Twitter and the posts are being submitted as expected. It's just that the model is never updated with the tweet id after the tweet is posted.

Comment: Can you check the Rails logs to see if a SQL UPDATE statement is generated? Maybe there are constraints on the database that are preventing the record from being updated.

Comment: If I bypass Resque I see the SQL update and it works, but if if I run it through Resque Scheduler, I don't see any output in the logs and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Update: Turns out there was a problem with my time picker that was randomly adding 24 hours onto the time. If I bypass that and set the time manually, even if I run it through Resque it goes through. I am still not able to see any log output though, so I have no idea what's going on under the hood in Resque.